# Status bar style issue

Tags: ios, statusbar

I need a `Light content` status bar for my iOS 8 app but it will show up as `Dark`. This thing persists and I can't get it work.

What I have tried so far:

- Setting the Status bar style in the `Info.plist`
- Setting the style through code with `UIApplication`
- Trying to set the `UINavigationBar`
- Setting the Status bar property for `UIViewControllers`

None of the above works, I get a `Light content` on the Loading Screen Storyboard but it gets dark as soon as it loads the starting `UIViewController` from the `storyboard`. Any thoughts why this is happening?

Comment: Try with following method in your view controller:


    - (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
    {
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    }

Comment: Already tried that, won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that code in your view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Comment: That solved it, with the mention that I had to repeat the process for EVERY view controller. Thank you

Comment: You can make some base controller for all of them